# Dissolve buffer lines with other data QGIS

Tags: merge, buffer, qgis

I have a problem where my buffer lines do not dissolve with the rest of the data. I want the buffer lines to "open" where they cross other data, right now it looks like the buffer data is layered on top of the other data.

In the picture I have pointed out a place where I would like the buffer to "merge" with the rest. There are plenty of those places, I have tried the dissolve but this is the only result I have gotten. [Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS81X.png).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is dissolve but you will need to dissolve the polygons based on a field from the attribute table. If all of the shapes that you want to merge have the same value in that field of the attribute table you'll be able to utilize dissolve.

Please see this post from gis.stackexchange:
[Merge intersecting polygons into one which are part of the same feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/merge-intersecting-polygons-into-one-which-are-part-of-the-same-feature/)